# TypeLoadException when calling Mouse.LeftClick()

Tags: c#, botsuite.net

I am trying to create a bot in C# and I am using [Bot Suite library](http://www.botsuite.net/tutorials/read/id/20140221).
I am able to move the mouse with desired speed. But I am unable to make mouse click. Here is the small code:

```
Point target = new Point(32, 875);
Thread.Sleep(3000);
Mouse.Move(target, true, 500);
Thread.Sleep(500);
Mouse.LeftClick();
```

On `Mouse.LeftClick()` I am getting this error:

> TypeLoadException was unhandled - Could not load type 'BotSuite.NativeMethods' from assembly 'BotSuite, Version=1.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the method 'SendMessage' has no implementation (no RVA).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

One of the native DLL imports is missing or incorrect. Re-download the project and re-compile it. I got this to work without any trouble just a day ago.

Comment: Thanks @user316 but can you please tell give link or code snippet of yours because I tried the same I have downloaded Binary and Master files both and try to add them. None of them seems to be a good solution.

Comment: https://github.com/wieschoo/BotSuite/archive/master.zip
This is what I use and it works. I think I know what your problem is - you must select "Allow unsafe code" in the project build settings.

Comment: I made changes to Build Settings..  the master file consists .cs files Now, can you please tell me how can I add the ready made Mouse class and Keyboard class.. I tried to add these classes but it shows error as the Same Native methods not found and all.. thanks

Comment: Your problem is the native functions are not getting imported. I'd suggest you to somehow send me a TeamViewer ID/Password to deal with it since I can really not explain you from here.

Comment: Sorry @user3162 I haven't installed Teamviewer!! just formatted my PC few days back. I will mail you my screen shot though if you can supply some mail id...